# .cpp files are converted to .cc files, when the project is imported to eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-indigo

I want to open the autodock source code in Eclipse. So I imported the source using the "Makefile Project with Existing Code" option.

The original source had files of .cpp extension. But after importing the source all the cpp files are changed to .cc extension.

How do I import the source and keep the same file extension? I'm using Eclipse Indigo CDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out :) First Create a new empty project New->Create C Project. Then right click on the new project in the project explorer, click import and select file system. Finally give the path to folder which contain the source files